# JSR 303 - Composition Constraint

Tags: java, hibernate-validator, bean-validation

How do I execute a `ConstraintValidator` within a `ConstraintValidator`?

I have a custom `@NotEmpty` and have a custom `ConstraintValidator`'s  for each type, and it works fine.

Now I want to create a class-level constraint that checks at least one of specified fields is not empty using those custom `ConstraintValidator`'s I already have. The constraint part(`@ClassNotEmpty`) is done, but the problem is the `ConstraintValidator` implementation. how do I obtain a `ConstraintValidator` instance for a given constraint? i.e.

```
isValid(Object value, ConstraintValidatorContext constraintValidatorContext)  {
    String[] fieldValues = getFieldValues(value, this.classNotEmpty.fieldNames());

    for (String fieldValue : fieldValues) {
        <What do I put here?>.isValid(fieldValue, constraintValidatorContext);
    }
}
```

Is there a way to do this without pulling up the validation routine to a helper class?

BTW, I'm using Spring and Hibernate Validator.

Comment: I think you can.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4308224/hibernate-validation-of-collections-of-primitives.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After further research, it appears that there is no known solution to obtain a `ConstraintValidator` instance for a given constraint, portable or not. A helper class seems to be the only way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have the info in front of me, but I remember reading something about validators that are composed of other validators. So if you have two validators A and B. You can define a third 'C' which is composed of the other two. Hunt through the doco, you should find it.

Just did a search, read this: http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/validator/reference/en-US/html/validator-customconstraints.html#validator-customconstraints-compound

It may be what you are looking for.

Comment: Actually, all examples I've seen are field-level composition of field-level constraints. I'm trying to do class-level composition of field-level constraints.