# JSR303 validation on collection of common objects

Tags: java, validation, collections, bean-validation

Is it possible to validate each element of a collection, based one or more delegate validation rules? For example:

```
@EachElement({@Min(1), @Max(12)})
private Set<Integer> monthNumbers;
```

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at [validator-collection](https://github.com/jirutka/validator-collection), with this library is very easy to use any Constraint Annotation on a collection of simple types.

```
@EachMin(1)
@EachMax(12)
private Set<Integer> monthNumbers;
```

Also see https://stackoverflow.com/a/16023061/2217862.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this answer: [Hibernate Validation of Collections of Primitives](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4308224/hibernate-validation-of-collections-of-primitives/4329039#4329039). That describes a solution which work for you but it is pretty complex. A simpler solution might be to implement a wrapper class for your `Integer` and declare `@Min` and `@Max` in that class. Than you can use

```
@Valid
private Set<MyIntegerWrapper> monthNumbers;
```

class MyIntegerWrapper:

```
class MyIntegerWrapper
{
   @Min(1)
   @Max(12)
   Integer myInteger;
}
```

Here you find some documentation for `@Valid`: [Object graphs](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/validator/4.0.1/reference/en/html_single/#d0e421)

Comment: What if I want to check that the Collection contains unique `name`?