# Javax Validation: Constraint Violations for Map

Tags: java, validation, dictionary, bean-validation, hibernate-validator

I use Map for localized values with locale as a key and String as value. For required fields I need to check that at least required locales are set - or at least some value is set. I have implemented validation annotation to be used on such Map fields and a corresponding validator. The problem is, how can I report a missing value? The property path that is used in UI to bind field errors/values, goes wrong each time:

```
// Domain object:
@LocalizationRequired
private Map<Locale, String> field;


// LocalizationRequiredValidator:
public boolean isValid(Map<Locale, String> map, ConstraintValidatorContext context) {
    if (requiredLocales.isEmpty()) {
        // Check that there exists any not null value
    } else {
        context.disableDefaultConstraintViolation();
        boolean valid = true;
        for (Locale requiredLocale : requiredLocales) { 
            if (map.get(requiredLocale) == null) { // e.g. fi
                valid = false;
                context.buildConstraintViolationWithTemplate("LocalizationRequired")
                // These end up in wrong property path:
                // .addNode(requiredLocale) 
                //    --> field.fi
                // .addNode("[" + requiredLocale + "]") 
                //    --> field.[fi]
                // .addNode(null).addNode(requiredLocale).inIterable() 
                //    --> field.fi
                // .addNode(null).addNode(null).inIterable().atKey(requiredLocale)
                //   --> field
                .addConstraintViolation();
            }
        }
        return valid;
    }
}
```

The correct path for this error is "field[fi]" but it appears I can only access indexed sub properties. In this case the object itself is indexed. I'm using Hibernate Validator.

Answer (score 3):

I was not able to find a way to report errors for indexed fields on element level. - Has this been overlooked in the spec?

Here's what I did:

Instead of Map, I used an "embeddable" bean with actual fields for all supported locales (e.g. LocalizedString(String fi, String en, etc). Then reported violations like this:

```
context.buildConstraintViolationWithTemplate("LocalizationRequired")
.addNode(requiredLocale)
.addConstraintViolation();
```

This is feasible in our case as we have a predefined set of supported languages, but it doesn't scale to indexed fields with arbitrary indexes.

Further more either Spring's `LocalValidatorFactoryBean` or Hibernate Validator does not properly support validation of embeddables. As the same component is used in different places with different validation requirements, I cannot use `@Valid` with actual validation annotations within the component itself - at least not without support for validation groups on `@Valid`.

The problem with Spring's `LocalValidatorFactoryBean` or Hibernate Validator is that the `invalidValue` of `ConstraintViolation` is LocalizedString ("field") instead of the value of the reported erroneous nested field ("field.fi"). Luckily this can be resolved by overriding  `LocalValidatorFactoryBean.processConstraintViolations` by removing that "custom FieldError registration with invalid value from ConstraintViolation" and reporting errors simply by

```
errors.rejectValue(field, errorCode, errorArgs, violation.getMessage());
```

This way Spring resolves the `invalidValue` using given `field`.

Answer (score 0):

This is a pretty interesting question. Right now I do not have time to test it myself :( , but this guy over here :

[Validation of a Collection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4308224/hibernate-validation-of-collections-of-primitives)

Seems to be able to Validate a Collection of elements. 
So if you switch to a Collection instead of a Map (which should be fairly easy), for example:

```
 class LocaleToString {
      private Locale locale;
      private String language;
 }

 @LocalizationRequired
 List<LocaleToString> locales;
```

You should be able to achieve what you want, I think.

Comment: Difference is the path to which actual validation errors are bound to. _Validation of a Collection_ reports all errors on collection level (locales) instead of element level (locales[1]). I was trying to get more specific errors (for Spring binding). I'm getting a pretty strong feeling that this kind of use cases have been overlooked in the spec... i.e. one would have to use a bean instead of indexed file.