# Hibernate or JPA constraint for List of Integer

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa

Is there such constraint that can be used for validating `List<Integer>` thus none of the values may contain null ?

**UPDATED**

I changed my code based on the answer provided here: [Hibernate Validation of Collections of Primitives](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4308224/hibernate-validation-of-collections-of-primitives)

This what I have tried:

```
@ValidCollection(elementType=Integer.class, constraints={NotNull.class})
private List<Integer> quantities;
```

My test case does not find any violations on below test code:

```
@Test
public void beanNotConstrained() {
    PurchaseForm pForm = new PurchaseForm();
    pForm.setQuantities(new ArrayList<Integer>());
    pForm.getQuantities().add(1);
    pForm.getQuantities().add(null);

    Validator validator = getValidator();

    Set<ConstraintViolation<PurchaseForm>> violations = validator.validate(pForm);
    for(ConstraintViolation<PurchaseForm> violation : violations) {
      logger.info(violation.getMessage());
    }
    Assert.assertEquals(1, violations.size());
}
```

Did I miss out anything here ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/4308224/1276804