# How to enable JSR308 null annotations on types in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, java-8, eclipse-jdt

With the release of Eclipse's java 8 support, I understood that null annotations on types (JSR 308) were possible, [as described here](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=392099%20as%20described%20here).
I have installed JDK8, and the [Java 8 feature patch](https://wiki.eclipse.org/JDT/Eclipse_Java_8_Support_For_Kepler) for Eclipse Kepler.
I was expecting to be able to declare a list that does not allow nulls like this:

```
List<@NonNull String> nonulls;
```

However, the compiler tells me that "The annotation @NonNull is disallowed for this location" :(

My project is configured to use compiler compliance level 1.8, and the org.eclipse.jdt.annotation jar is included in the class path.

What am I missing here?

Regards,

Comment: I think you should read this : http://types.cs.washington.edu/jsr308/

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java 8, Type Annotations and JSR 308](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20197440/java-8-type-annotations-and-jsr-308)

Comment: @SvetlinZarev The checker framework you are referring to is not what I mean. I'm trying to use Eclipse's NonNull annotations on types, which are supported by the java 8 feature patch I mentioned.

Comment: @SvetlinZarev It's not exactly a duplicate; my question is specifically about Eclipse. The mentioned question is about type annotations in general.

Comment: @Tom What is `@NonNull`'s package? The annotation should be defined with `@Target(ElementType.TYPE_USE)`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem was caused by the way I added the Eclipse annotation jar to the project's build path. I used the Quick Fix called "*Copy library with default null annotations to build path*", which adds an old version of the jar (`org.eclipse.jdt.annotation_1.1.0.v20140129-1625.jar`). This version is the pre-java-8 version, and does not support type annotations.

The fix is to put the correct (java-8) version of the jar on the build path. This version came with the [Kepler Java 8 feature patch](https://wiki.eclipse.org/JDT/Eclipse_Java_8_Support_For_Kepler), and is located in the 'plugins' directory in the Eclipse installation directory: `org.eclipse.jdt.annotation_2.0.0.v20140317-1808.jar`. If you add this jar to your build path, type annotations work fine.

Credits to [Thomas Schindl](http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/m/1273950/#msg_1273950)!