# How to use Java Bean Validators (JSR-303/JSR-349) on elements of an array/list/collection

Tags: java, validation, bean-validation

I'm new to using Java Bean validation (JSR-303/JSR-349/Hibernate Validator), and understand the general concepts.  However, I'm not sure how to validate the contents of an composed type vs the type itself.

For example:

```
@NotNull
private List<String> myString;
```

will validate that the List myString is not null, but does nothing for validating the contents of the list itself.  Or given other types of validators (Min/Max/etc), how do I validate the individual elements of the List?  Is there a generic solution for any composed type?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no easy generic solution as of Bean Validation 1.0/1.1. You could implement a custom constraint like `@NoNullElements`:

```
@NoNullElements
private List<String> myStrings;
```

The constraint's validator would iterate over the list and check that no element is null. Another approach is to wrap your String into a more domain-specific type:

```
public class EmailAddress {

    @NotNull
    @Email
    private String value;

    //...
}
```

And apply cascaded validation to the list via `@Valid`:

```
@Valid
private List<EmailAddress> addresses;
```

Having such a domain-specific data type is often helpful anyways to convey a data element's meaning as it is passed through an application.

In the future a generic solution for the issue may be to use annotations on type parameters as supported by Java 8 but that's only an idea at this point:

```
private List<@NotNull String> myStrings;
```

Comment: Thanks!  That's pretty much what I had come up with as well, however I was hoping that there would have been built-in support for aggregate constructs, but apparently that is missing.

Comment: `List<@NotNull String>` is supported as a proprietary feature in recent versions of Hibernate Validator 5.x and will be official part of the Bean Validation 2.0 spec.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [validator-collection](https://github.com/jirutka/validator-collection) – it’s very easy to use any Constraint Annotation on a collection of simple types with this library. Also see https://stackoverflow.com/a/16023061/2217862.

Comment: Thanks for sharing.  Will definitely take a closer look at it, but looks promising.

Answer (score 0):

Upcoming jsr 380 (bean validation 2.0) will allow to put constraints annotation to argument type.

@Valid
private List<@NotNull String> myString;

For now Bean Validation 1.1 in you can create custom constraints that checks null condition.

Comment: You don't need the `@Valid` annotation here; when the type containing `myString(s)` is validated, the elements of that list will be validated too and the `@NotNull` constraint be applied to each of them.

Answer (score 0):

### Bean Validation 2.0/Hibernate Validator 6.0

Bean Validation 2.0 (of which Hibernate Validator 6.0 is the reference implementation) allows using its validation annotations directly on generic type arguments.  This is noted in the [Hibernate 6.0 release documentation](https://hibernate.org/validator/releases/6.0/#bean-validation-2-0):

> Hibernate Validator 6.0 is the Reference Implementation of the Bean Validation 2.0 specification so it comes with all its new features:
>
> - First class support of container element constraints and cascaded validation (think `private Map<@Valid @NotNull OrderCategory, List<@Valid @NotNull Order>> orderByCategories;`);

If the project is using Java 8 with Bean Validation 2.0, this feature can be used to validate each element of the list:

```java
private List<@NotNull String> myString; // Validate that none of the list items is null
```

### Bean Validation 1.2/Hibernate Validator 5.2

Hibernate 5.2 (with Bean Validation 1.2) added a limited version of the feature to allow validation annotations directly on generic type arguments.  However, none of its built-in Bean Validation or Hibernate Validation constraints could be used in this manner, as the annotations do not specify `ElementType.TYPE_USE` for backwards-compatibility reasons.  Additionally, type argument constraints could be specified for map values but not map keys.  This is all described in the [Hibernate Validator 5.2 documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/validator/5.2/reference/en-US/html_single/#type-arguments-constraints):

> Starting from Java 8, it is possible to specify constraints directly on the type argument of a parameterized type.  However, this requires that `ElementType.TYPE_USE` is specified via `@Target` in the constraint definition.  To maintain backwards compatibility, built-in Bean Validation as well as Hibernate Validator specific constraints do not yet specify `ElementType.TYPE_USE`.
>
> [...]
>
> When applying constraints on an Iterable type argument, Hibernate Validator will validate each element.
>
> [...]
>
> Type argument constraints are also validated for map values. Constraints on the key are ignored.

### Summary

In summary, if the code is using Java 8 with Bean Validation 2.0 (such as Hibernate Validator 6), the generic list & map type arguments can be annotated:

```java
private List<@NotNull String> myString;
```

If the code is using Java 8 with Bean Validation 1.2 and Hibernate Validator 5.2, custom validation annotations can be written with `TYPE_USE` in its definition, and applied to the generic type of the collection or map value:

```java
private List<@MyCustomNotNull String> myString;
```

If the code is not using Java 8 or is on a version of Hibernate Validator prior to 5.2, a custom constraint could be written which verifies every element of a collection or map and applied to the collection or map itself.

```java
@MyCustomNotNullElements
private List<String> myString;
```