# Adding @NotNull or Pattern constraints on List<String>

Tags: java, json, validation, hibernate-validator, jsr

How can we ensure the individual strings inside a list are not null/blank or follow  a specific pattern

```
@NotNull
List<String> emailIds;
```

I also want to add a pattern

`@Pattern("\b[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}\b.")`

but I can live without it.But I would definitely like to have a constraint which will check if any strings inside a list are null or blank. Also how would the Json schema look like

```
"ids": {
      "description": "The  ids associated with this.", 
    "type": "array",
        "minItems": 1,
        "items": {
        "type": "string",
         "required" :true }
 }

"required" :true does not seem to do the job
```

Comment: Why not create an Object rather than String, and enforce the pattern within the object creation.  Say,  List<EMailInfo> eMailIds;   Class EMailInfo (String emailid) .. check for valid, return null if bad; and use method get emailIds in that class

Comment: Create a derived class of List, whose add() method override does all that?

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4308224/hibernate-validation-of-collections-of-primitives

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can create a simple wrapper class for the e-mail String:

```
public class EmailAddress {

    @Pattern("\b[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+.[A-Z]{2,4}\b.")
    String email;

    //getters and setters
}
```

Then mark the field `@Valid` in your existing object:

```
@NotNull
@Valid
List<EmailAddress> emailIds;
```

The validator will then validate each object in the list.

Answer (score 63):

Bean validation 2.0 (Hibernate Validator 6.0.1 and above) supports validating container elements by annotating type arguments of parameterized types.  Example:

```
List<@Positive Integer> positiveNumbers;
```

Or even (although a bit busy):

```
List<@NotNull @Pattern(regexp="\\b[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+.[A-Z]{2,4}\\b") String> emails;
```

References:

- http://beanvalidation.org/2.0/
- https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/validator/reference/en-US/html_single/#_with_code_list_code

Answer (score 9):

You don’t have to use any wrapper class just to validate a list of strings. Just use `@EachPattern` constraint from [validator-collection](https://github.com/jirutka/validator-collection):

```
@NotNull
@EachPattern(regexp="\b[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+.[A-Z]{2,4}\b.")
List<String> values;
```

And that’s all. Easy, right? See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16023061/2217862) SO answer for more information.

Comment: not sure i would advocate to use a third party library just to validate a list of strings either.

Comment: especially since it's not even actively updated anymore

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, use a wrapper class for the object, and have your own verification on the methods:

```
public class ListWrapper<E> {

    private List<E> list = new ArrayList<>();
    private Pattern check = /*pattern*/;

    public boolean add(E obj) {
        if (this.verify(obj)) {
            return list.add(obj);
        }
        return false;
    }

    //etc

    public boolean verify(E obj) {
        //check pattern and for null
    }
```

Alternatively, just use a custom object for the list

Comment: I would rather extend arraylist than wrap it. Right now, methods that accept List<T> as parameter cannot accept this class

Comment: To each their own, would depend on the use-case I suppose