# Validate elements of a String array with Java Bean Validation

Tags: java, bean-validation, indexed-properties

I have a simple class that has one of its properties as a String array. As per [this](http://beanvalidation.org/1.1/spec/#constraintdeclarationvalidationprocess-validationroutine) document, using @Valid on an array, collection etc. will recursively validate each element of the array/collection.

```
@Valid
@Pattern(regexp="^[_ A-Za-z0-9]+$")
public String[] defaultAppAdminRoles;
```

the above annotation on the property generates the following exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.validation.UnexpectedTypeException: No validator could be found for type java.lang.String[]. See: @Pattern at public java.lang.String[] com.hm.vigil.platform.ops.model.Application.defaultAppAdminRoles
at org.apache.bval.jsr303.AnnotationProcessor.checkOneType(AnnotationProcessor.java:326)
at org.apache.bval.jsr303.AnnotationProcessor.getConstraintValidator(AnnotationProcessor.java:301)
at org.apache.bval.jsr303.AnnotationProcessor.applyConstraint(AnnotationProcessor.java:241)
at org.apache.bval.jsr303.AnnotationProcessor.processAnnotation(AnnotationProcessor.java:149)
at org.apache.bval.jsr303.AnnotationProcessor.processAnnotations(AnnotationProcessor.java:90)
at org.apache.bval.jsr303.Jsr303MetaBeanFactory.processClass(Jsr303MetaBeanFactory.java:134)
at org.apache.bval.jsr303.Jsr303MetaBeanFactory.buildMetaBean(Jsr303MetaBeanFactory.java:95)
at org.apache.bval.MetaBeanBuilder.buildForClass(MetaBeanBuilder.java:131)
at org.apache.bval.MetaBeanManager.findForClass(MetaBeanManager.java:102)
at org.apache.bval.jsr303.ClassValidator.validate(ClassValidator.java:140)
at com.hm.vigil.platform.commons.AbstractValidatable.isValid(AbstractValidatable.java:33)
at com.hm.vigil.platform.ops.model.Application.main(Application.java:54)
```

I am using Apache BVal as validation provider.

The question, is the above method correct?

If it is not correct, what is the correct way to validate an array/collection with bean validation?

If it is correct, then is it some limitation of Apache BVal?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By adding the `@Valid` annotation like you've done, the validation algorithm is applied on each element (validation of the element constraints).

In your case the String class has no constraints. The `@Pattern` constraint you've added is applied to the array and not on each element of it. Since `@Pattern` constraint cannot be applied on a array, you are getting an error message.

You can create a custom validation constraint for your array (see [Hibernate docs](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/validator/4.2/reference/en-US/html_single/#validator-customconstraints) for more info) or you can use a wrapper class like @Jordi Castilla mentioned.

Answer (score 18):

Another thing worth mentioning is the introduction of type annotation in Java 8 which lets you annotate parameterized type

```
private List<@MyPattern String> defaultAppAdminRoles;
```

It's not yet in the bean-validation standard (surely in next version) but already available in hibernate-validator 5.2.1. [Blog entry](http://in.relation.to/2015/07/30/hibernate-validator-521-final/) here for further information.

Comment: https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/validator/reference/en-US/html_single/#type-arguments-constraints

Comment: NOTE: for backward compatibility it requires creation of custom validator.

Answer (score 3):

First... i'm not sure... but `@Pattern` only accepts `regex`, right? Correct sintax is not:

```
@Pattern("^[_ A-Za-z0-9]+$")   // delete 'regexp='
```

If this is not the problem you can create a [wrapper class](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22233776/3850595) with validators in the attributes:

```
public class Role {

    @Pattern(regexp="^[_ A-Za-z0-9]+$")
    String adminRole;

    //getters and setters
}
```

Then just need to mark the field `@Valid` in your existing object:

```
@Valid
Role[] defaultAppAdminRoles;
```

Comment: You'd also need to add single String Constructor in your Wrapper class for implementing this.
`public Role(String adminRole){  this.adminRole = adminRole; }`