# Hibernate length validator for List<String>

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate-validator

For the address field, instead of creating 3 parameters

```
String addr1;
String addr2;
String addr3;
```

I have listed it as,

```
List<String> addressLines;
```

Now the issue is how I can add min, max length of string fields. If it's one at a time, I can add @Max(40)

One way I can think is by adding String to a class, and make a list of that class and there validate. But, it's just a workaround.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Adding @NotNull or Pattern constraints on List<String>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22233512/adding-notnull-or-pattern-constraints-on-liststring) replacing the `@NotNull` to your `@Max(40)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can annotate the type parameter:

```
List<@Max(40) String> addressLines;
```