# How to validate size of elements inside a list with javax?

Tags: java, validation

How can I validate the length of the elements *inside* a list with `javax.validation`?

```
@Size(min = 2, max = 3)
private String value;

private List<String> list;
```

Comment: I think you should read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4308224/hibernate-validation-of-collections-of-primitives) topic and all of those solutions.

Answer (score -1):

hibernate-validator 5.2.x will be supporting the following syntax, which is great:

`List<@Length(min = 2, max = 3) String> list;`

Comment: I have `5.2.1.final` and `@Length not applicable to type use`.

Comment: I've succeeded using `@Size` instead of `@Length` with hibernate-validator 6.2.x