# Spring StandardMultipartHttpServletRequest validation

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, bean-validation

Is there any possibility to validate [`StandardMultipartHttpServletRequest`](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring/4.1.6.RELEASE/javadoc-api/index.html?org/springframework/web/multipart/support/StandardMultipartHttpServletRequest.html) using standard [`@Valid`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/validation/Valid.html) annotation and custom [`Validator`](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring/4.1.6.RELEASE/javadoc-api/index.html?org/springframework/web/multipart/support/StandardMultipartHttpServletRequest.html)?

I've implemented such validator, annotated method param in controller the validator is not invoked.

Comment: I've implemented validator for `MultipartFile` interface and it works. Why do you need to validate exactly `StandardMultipartHttpServletRequest`?

Comment: @SlavaSemushin, since this is the argument of the method in controller. From it I extract the upload files.

Comment: Yes, and `StandardMultipartHttpServletRequest` implements `MultipartFile`. If you don't use some implementation specific methods then you can replace argument type by this interface. I don't see what is your problem here. Implement custom validator, put annotation, add `@Valid` annotation, etc.

Comment: @SlavaSemushin, could you please provide an example? I need to validate an `List<MultipartFile>` object.

Comment: I can provide example (https://github.com/php-coder/mystamps/blob/d8da294f991ccdc7495b150f87b260a635d8d248/src/main/java/ru/mystamps/web/validation/jsr303/NotEmptyFileValidator.java) but it's for validation single object. Unfortunately you didn't mention that fact in your question. Validating collection is a bit different. Dod you saw this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4308224/hibernate-validation-of-collections-of-primitives ?

Comment: @SlavaSemushin, thanks. I've already resolved it. Will add my answer later on.

Comment: @SlavaSemushin, answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've figured it out myself. To make it work you need a DTO:

```
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.Setter;
import org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile;

import java.util.List;

@Getter
@Setter
public class NewOrderFilesDTO {
    List<MultipartFile> files;
}
```

Then, a validator:

```
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.validation.Errors;
import org.springframework.validation.Validator;
import org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile;

import java.util.List;

import static org.springframework.util.CollectionUtils.isEmpty;

@Component
public class NewOrderFilesValidator implements Validator {

    private static final String MIME_TYPE_PDF = "application/pdf";
    private static final long ALLOWED_SIZE = 3 * 1024 * 1024;

    @Override
    public void validate(Object target, Errors errors) {
        if (target == null) {
            return;
        }

        NewOrderFilesDTO newOrderFilesDTO = (NewOrderFilesDTO) target;
        List<MultipartFile> newOrderFiles = newOrderFilesDTO.getFiles();

        if (isEmpty(newOrderFiles)) {
            return;
        }

        for (MultipartFile file : newOrderFiles) {
            if (!MIME_TYPE_PDF.equals(file.getContentType())) {
                errors.rejectValue(file.getName(), file.getName(), "'application/pdf' files allowed only!");
            }

            if (file.getSize() > ALLOWED_SIZE) {
                errors.rejectValue(file.getName(), file.getName(), "File size allowed up to 3MB!");
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean supports(Class<?> cls) {
        return NewOrderFilesDTO.class.equals(cls);
    }
}
```

And finally a controller:

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.WebDataBinder;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.InitBinder;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseStatus;

import javax.validation.Valid;

import static org.springframework.http.HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT;
import static org.springframework.http.MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE;
import static org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod.POST;

@Controller
class OrderController {

    private final NewOrderFilesValidator newOrderFilesValidator;

    @Autowired
    OrderController(NewOrderFilesValidator newOrderFilesValidator) {
        this.newOrderFilesValidator = newOrderFilesValidator;
    }

    @InitBinder("newOrderFiles")
    void initOrderFilesBinder(WebDataBinder binder) {
        binder.addValidators(newOrderFilesValidator);
    }

    @ResponseStatus(NO_CONTENT)
    @RequestMapping(value = ORDERS_PATH, method = POST, consumes = MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE)
    void createOrder(
            @Valid @ModelAttribute NewOrderFilesDTO newOrderFiles
    ) {

    }
}
```

With the configuration above the DTO will be validated automatically by spring.

Comment: Just to let you know that check for a file type is weak because it's based on the headers from user's request.

Comment: @SlavaSemushin, yes I know that. Maybe will verify it using an another way.

Comment: Another room for improvement would be to transform your validator to JSR-303 validator. In this case it can be reused easily and wouldn't depend on Spring.