# Using @Valid in Spring MVC to validate a list of String

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-validator

My Pojo looks like this -

```
public class Employee {

   @Pattern(regexp="some regex")

   private String Address;

   **// How do I validate each element in list for the a regex pattern**

   private List<String> names; 
}
```

My goal is to validate each String in the list 'names' for a regex. How can I achieve that use @Valid in spring mvc validation support ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4308224/hibernate-validation-of-collections-of-primitives

Comment: thanks for pointing to right post..